# Check for all the values from a Many to Many field in django

Tags: python, django

I want to query a complete list of possible language ids and show results when all the languages are present in the result. This is what I am doing right now.

So, this gets the result, but if I have say German and French for one person, it will display it as two results.

```
langknown = string2 + "__lang_known__id__in"    
l = Q()
args = {langknown:lang}
l = l & Q (**args)
```

Comment: You would use the `.distinct()` filter? Or you could just remove duplicates in python code.

Comment: It would still be an OR logic.. so if it contains only German, it shows in the result.. i want to implement a strict AND logic.